# returning opengl display callback in D

Tags: opengl, d

I've written a simple hello world opengl program in D, using the converted gl headers [here](http://www.dsource.org/projects/bindings/browser/trunk/gl).

My code so far:

```
import std.string;
import c.gl.glut;

Display_callback display()
{
    return Display_callback // line 7
    {
        return; // just display a blank window
    };
} // line 10

void main(string[] args)
{
    glutInit(args.length, args);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello World");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

My problem is with the `display()` function.  `glutDisplayFunc()` expects a function that returns a `Display_callback`, which is typedef'd as `typedef GLvoid function() Display_callback;`.  When I try to compile, dmd says

```
line 7: found '{' when expecting ';' following return statement
line 10: unrecognized declaration
```

How do I properly return the `Display_callback` here?  Also, how do I change D strings and string literals into `char*`?  My calls to `glutInit` and `glutCreateWindow` don't like the D strings they're getting.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use nested functions or methods as function types, since they rely on contextual information being available (the stack or the object, respectively). You'll have to use a static or file scope function:

```
void displayEmptyWindow () {
    return;
}

Display_callback display() {
    return &displayEmptyWindow;
}
```

**EDIT:** If you're using D2, you can convert a string into a C string with code such as the following:

```
string str = "test string";

// add one for the required NUL terminator for C
char[] mutableString = new char[str.length + 1];
mutableString[] = str[];
mutableString[str.length] = '\0';

// and, finally, get a pointer to the contents of the array
char* cString = mutableString.ptr;
```

If you know for sure that the function you're calling won't modify the string, you can simplify this a bit:

```
someCFunction(cast(char*)toStringz(str));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, attempting to return `displayEmptyWindow` results in a `cannot implicitly convert expression (&displayWindow()) of type void* to Display_callback` error (essentially what I got when I tried to define `display` as simply returning void).  `toStringz()` also returns `immutable(char)*`, which opengl still doesn't like.

Comment: @Max The code I posted, when copied verbatim, worked for me. Did you add `()` to the return statement by accident? As for the string problem, you're right. I'll update my answer with the correct information.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did wrong last night, but trying your code again worked.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `toStringz` in `std.string`?

Comment: @Bernard `toStringz` returns `immutable(char)*`, so it can't be passed to any functions that need to modify the string.

Answer (score 0):

glutDisplayFunc() expects a function that takes no parameters returns GLvoid (i.e. nothing). The typedef you refer is creating a typedef called Display_callback that is a type of a function that accepts no parameters and returns nothing, such as:

```
GLvoid myGLCallback()
{
    return; // do nothing
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.  `Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (myGLCallback()) of type void to Display_callback`

Comment: GLvoid myGLCallBack() { } /* ... etc ... */ glutDisplayFunc(myGLCallBack); // this doesn't work? If not, please post your new code with these changes